# How to know if index of splitting a string exist C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, split

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to check if there's any value to a string split from a file.

Example, this is my file with their values:

```
Value1 Value2 Value3
Value1 Value2
Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5
```

if I get the first line I'll have something like:

```
line = "Value1 Value2 Value3"
```

In this case the, can have 5 values, mi line contains just 3, in my code want to validate if 5 exist. It should be mentioned that I'm validating all the values (5).

Example:

```
if (line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0] == null)
{  
      //do something
}
else{
      //do something else
}

if (line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1] == null)
{  
      //do something
}
else{
      //do something else
}


if (line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2] == null)
{  
      //do something
}
else{
      //do something else
}

if (line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[3] == null)
{  
      //do something
}
else{
      //do something else
}

if (line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[4] == null)
{  
      //do something
}
else{
      //do something else
}
```

I'm getting an exception due [3] is out of range just for the first line.

Any idea how can I solve that?

Comment: Check if the length is 3 then do whatever you want with the element at index 2

Comment: check length of split?

Comment: Just separate it into two line and check the length
you don't have to put it all on one line

Comment: You're trying to check the value of an array at an index that does not exist. Split the string into an array, then check the length of the array to see if there are 3 items.

Comment: What about if it could has 4 values, and sometimes 3rd value or 4th value does not exist?

Comment: Don't remove empty strings?

Comment: var result = line.Split(//  your code);
if (result.Length == 3) 
// code

unless you mean you want 3 regardless of 2 existing

Comment: No need to split the string, just check `line.Contains("Value3");`

Comment: So far checking length seem to be what you want (there are plenty of duplicates on that topic). If you actually interested in something else make sure to [edit] post to clarify. I.e. your remark about "and sometimes 3rd value or 4th value does not exist" is very confusing - how would one figure out if string with 3 values missing second or third one?

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried something like:

```
if (line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length >= 3)
{
    // do something
}
```

This will tell you if there are at least three elements in the array that was returned by calling the Split() method.

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed out in comments, all you have to do is to split the lines and count the elements of the output array:

```
foreach (String line in lines)
{
    String[] split = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    switch (split.Length)
    {
        case 1:
            // Do something...
            break;

        case 2:
            // Do something...
            break;

        case 3:
            // Do something...
            break;

        case 4:
            // Do something...
            break;

        case 5:
            // Do something...
            break;

        default:
            // Error?
            break;
    }
}
```

Visit [this link](http://rextester.com/INHAG34681) for a working demo.

**ANSWER UPDATED**

Answer (score 0):

```
line = "Value1 Value2 Value3"
var NumberOfItems = line.Split(' ').length
```

You will get any element by using index `line.Split(' ')[0]` to `line.Split(' ')[NumberOfItems-1]`